# return an HTTP response from a secondary method in Flask

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I'm not sure how to Google this, but basically I have a Flask Restful API that typically returns responses like this:

In my main file:

```
api.add_resource(my_package.MyClass,'/path/to/some/stuff')
```

Then in my_package.py:

```
class MyClass(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return "hello world"
```

So basically that post method is processing things posted to `/path/to/some/stuff`. But my code is getting a bit more complex, and so I want to call other methods (which are NOT API resources) from `post()`, like:

```
class MyClass(Resource):

    def validate_something(xyz)
        ...do some validation...
        if (validation_fails):
            return "Your validation has failed!"

    def post(self):
        validate_something(xyz)
        return "hello world"
```

The problem is, it seems that I can't return (to the user who hit my API) a response from my code unless it's in one of these API-enabled methods like `post()`. When I return "Your validation has failed!" above, it doesn't go to the user, it just goes to `post()` as a return value. Is there any way I can basically "upgrade" `validate_something()` so it can return responses directly? Or alternatively can I hijack the return statement to specify whether I want to return to the user or just return to the calling method?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`return` isn't hooked up to your end user by some sort of magic - the client is always going to get whatever you're returning *from the view method*. Calling another function within your view can't force your view method to return, you have to do it explicitly.

You could do something like this:

```
class MyClass(Resource):

    def validate_something(xyz)
        ...do some validation...
        if (validation_fails):
            return "Your validation has failed!"

    def post(self):
        validation = validate_something(xyz)
        if validation is not None: # if validation passes, validate_something currently has no return value so it will return None
            return validation
        return "hello world"
```

However, I don't think this makes for better code. Ideally your `validate_something` method should only have one job: to validate. Not to form end user responses. Let your view method handle that:

```
class MyClass(Resource):

    def validate_something(xyz)
        ...do some validation...
        if (validation_fails):
            return False
        return True

    def post(self):
        validated = validate_something(xyz)
        if not validated:
            return "Your validation has failed!"
        return "hello world"
```

It's a much better separation of concerns

Comment: I see what you mean, but the use case is where certain types of validation need to occur for a lot of different view functions. For example, if I'm checking if I couldn't find their user in the database and I want to do that for 10 different functions, I wanted to only write the error message once in a helper method. So I guess I can do that with a complex return type where error message is one entry, it just doesn't seem super elegant.